# vim how to insert line with the values extracted from the xml file

Tags: vim, insert, pattern-matching

I have an `xml` file in which I expect to find some particular tags with values that I want to use to build an url. I would like to:

1. find these values
2. make an url with them
3. insert this url at the beginning of a file

For example, given `xml` file starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file_1_doc>
    <biul>1</biul>
    <poz>33792</poz>          
    <date_pub>2015-02-16</date_pub>

(...)
```

I want to produce an url in the base form:

```
http://foo.com/index.php?biul=show&position=[poz]&publdate=[date_pub]
```

having for the example above:

```
http://foo.com/index.php?biul=show&position=33792&publdate=2015-02-16
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: I agree with @Ingo Karkat pointing out that I did not include any evidence of my previous effort. I am new to `vim` and by this description I wanted to stress my aim of regexing text to make it a variable (the exact way I would like to use it). 
I have been serching the web for help but, for the lack of experience, I was not succesful of make use of hints such "just try this method" if there was no example provided.
I guess the conclusion is I wanted the result to quickly as for my expercience, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. find these values

You need an XML parser; Vim cannot do this properly (unless the XML is always consistently structured and doesn't use specials like XML named entities, where you *may* attempt to parse using regular expression (`matchstr()`), but read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) first).

Vim can embed various scripting languages, e.g. Python (`:help if_pyth.txt`). With their default libraries, XML parsing shouldn't be a big problem. Else, you can invoke an external tool (e.g. [xmlstar](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)) via `system()`.

> 2. make an url with them

Once you've got the parsed XML in Vim variable(s), this can be comfortably done via `printf()`.

> 3. insert this url at the beginning of a file

Again, various easy ways. For a completely new line, `:call append()`; to add to a line, either `:execute 'normal! a' . text` or the lower-level `call setline(, getline(1) . ...)`.

Comment: Thank you @Ingo Karkat for your attention! By the time I have learned how to make use of `matchstr()` properly, I realised in my case making a few replace actions is going to work, too. I also thank you for asnwering despite your thoughts of me not having put enough effort in this issue at first.